# Cakephp PubNub tutorial

Tags: cakephp, geolocation, pubnub

I want to use PubNub's api in my cakephp app, but I cannot find any cakephp plugins for pubnub. Essentially I want to use the pubnub api to deliver realtime messages about a user's geolocation using the google maps geolocation api. Are there any tutorials on how to integrate pubnub with cakephp apps?

Comment: Alex: glad you're trying to figure out new stuff!  Unfortunately, StackOverflow is meant for specific technical questions.  Your question is more something that should be directed to Google, Bing...etc. If you can't find a good tutorial, and have a specific question about how to implement code, please feel free to ask that here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a PubNub plugin for CakePHP.  Looks like somebody had an idea for it, but it isn't developed:  https://github.com/siran/pubnub

I don't personally know much about PubNub, but if you are using the PHP API then I guess what you should do is download it - https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/php/3.3 - into the vendors directory in your app (e.g. `app/Vendor/PubNub`) and start using it in your Cake app where you need it.  You might have to write your own Cake code or classes to help make working with the API easier and your code more reusable, but I can't really advise on that.

However, it looks like the most popular option is the JavaScript API, which you wouldn't really need any special integration for with CakePHP.  You would just include the PubNub script in your view or your layout if you are using it everywhere in your application:

http://www.pubnub.com/account-javascript-api-include